# Angular tests: How to expect element events to be triggered?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-directive

I'm decorating forms like this:

```
angular.module('Validation').directive('form', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var inputs = element[0].querySelectorAll('[name]');

      element.on('submit', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          angular.element(inputs[i]).triggerHandler('blur');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Now, I'm trying to test this directive:

```
describe('Directive: form', function() {
  beforeEach(module('Validation'));

  var $rootScope, $compile, scope, form, input, textarea;

  function compileElement(elementHtml) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    form = angular.element(elementHtml);
    input = form.find('input');
    textarea = form.find('textarea');
    $compile(form)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;

    compileElement('<form><input type="text" name="email"><textarea name="message"></textarea></form>');
  }));

  it('should trigger "blur" on all inputs when submitted', function() {
    spyOn(input, 'trigger');
    form.triggerHandler('submit');
    expect(input.trigger).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Expected spy trigger to have been called.
  });
});
```

But, the test fails.

What's the right Angular way to test this directive?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Are you testing in phantomJS or another headless browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some problems:

1) `input = form.find('input');` and `angular.element(inputs[i]);` are 2 **different** wrapper objects wrapping the same underlying DOM object.

2) You should create a spy on `triggerHandler` instead.

3) You're working directly with DOM which is difficult to unit-test.

An example of this is: `angular.element(inputs[i])` **is not injected** so that we have difficulty faking it in our unit tests.

To ensure that point **1)** returns the same object. We can fake the `angular.element` to return a **pre-trained** value which is the `input = form.find('input');`

```
//Jasmine 1.3: andCallFake
//Jasmine 2.0: and.callFake
angular.element = jasmine.createSpy("angular.element").and.callFake(function(){
         return input; //return the same object created by form.find('input');
});
```

**Side note:** As `form` is already an angularJs directive, to avoid conflicting with an already defined directive, you should create another directive and apply it to the `form`. Something like this:

```
<form mycustomdirective></form>
```

I'm not sure if this is necessary. Because we're spying on a global function (angular.element) which may be used in many places, we may need to save the previous function and restore it at the end of the test. Your complete source code looks like this:

```
it('should trigger "blur" on all inputs when submitted', function() {

    var angularElement = angular.element; //save previous function

    angular.element = jasmine.createSpy("angular.element").and.callFake(function(){
         return input;
    });

    spyOn(input, 'triggerHandler');
    form.triggerHandler('submit');

    angular.element = angularElement; //restore
    expect(input.triggerHandler).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Expected spy trigger to have been called.
  });
```

[Running DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EH2twINtdwWdO4ESFWdH?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something to do with raising the 'submit' event during the test.

The angular team have created a pretty funky class to help them do this it seems to cover a lot of edge cases - see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngScenario/browserTrigger.js

While this helper is from ngScenario I use it in my unit tests to overcome problems raising some events in headless browsers such as PhantomJS.

I had to use this to test a very similar directive that performs an action when a form is submitted see the test here https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-auto-validate/blob/master/tests/config/ngSubmitDecorator.spec.js (see line 38).

I had to use this as I am using a headless browser for development testing purposes.  It seems that to trigger an event in this type of browser the element that is triggering the event has to be attached to the dom as well.

Also as the form directive is one that angular already has you should either decorate this directive or give this directive a new name.  I would actually suggest you decorate the ngSubmit directive instead of the form directive as this is more gear towards submitting a form.  I actually have a very good example of this as I did this in the validation module I have open sourced.  This should give you a very good start.

The directive source is [here](https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-auto-validate/blob/master/src/config/ngSubmitDecorator.js)

The directive tests are [here](https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-auto-validate/blob/master/tests/config/ngSubmitDecorator.spec.js)

Comment: _"Also as the form directive is one that angular already has you should either decorate this directive or give this directive a new name."_ Why is that ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I believe it would conflict with the angular form directive and it would appear less like voodoo code if a directive with a clear meaning was used instead i.e. blur-contorls-on-submit="" instead of it just magically happening on every form.  An application should be composed of meaningful parts and just because we are in html land doesn't mean we should follow the single responsibility principle with directives (my 10 cents anyway!!!! :-) )

Comment: I would not conflict. There can be as many directives with the same name as you want (and all are applied to the element). It really depends on what the user wants. If you want something applied to all forms then it makes sense to declare another `form` directive instead of having to add an extra directive on every form.

Comment: I disagree with applying it to the form directive.  Working in teams people can't be expected to know every bit of code and if something weirdly starts happening to the form when they submit it will cost them time and effort to find out why and may even lead to code hacks to get it to stop doing this.  I think directives should be short and sharp and define what they do to the element they to avoid confusion.

Comment: You are missing the point here. Again: _"If you want something applied to **all** forms then it makes sense to declare another form directive"_ It is a project-level dicision. If you need something applied to all forms, then creating a directive with a different name will not automatically apply it to everyones forms. You need to inform all other members anyway.

Comment: @ExpertSystem-I don't think I am missing the point.I am making the point that having this cloaked behaviour on all forms is a bad idea for a number of reasons, yes you get it generically applied but are all members of your team old and new going to always remember that this behaviour happens and indeed want it to happen?  It should be explicitly defined on another directive which makes the behaviour reusable and explict and it becomes an active decision to use it.  Anyway this is a bad example as when the form is submitted clicking the submit button would cause the focused input to blur anyway

Comment: What I am saying is that if (for whatever weird and pervert reason) you want ALL forms in your app to have a specific behaviour (and that behaviour is not intrusive) then it is a better idea to have an extra `form` directive. As you said, if you have a different directive then you need to make sure that all team-members, old and new, will be aware of the fact that you want then to ALWAYS use that directive on forms and there is always the chance that they forget. Anyway, I feel we are repeating ourselves, so... :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem - thanks for letting me know about the ability to do multiple directives, as you said it would come in useful in some scenarios :-)

Comment: this looks like integration test (end to end test), not unit test.

Comment: @KhanhTO - it is unit testing, what makes you think that?

Comment: because there is something about ng-scenario which is end to end test

Comment: @KhanhTO see the edit - although this helper function is from ngScenario I use it in my unit test to overcome problems and difference to raise events in headless browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking into the **blur** event:

```
  it('should trigger "blur" on all inputs when submitted', function() {
    var blurCalled = false;
    input.on('blur', function() { blurCalled = true; });
    form.triggerHandler('submit');
    expect(blurCalled).toBe(true);
  });
```